# unbelievable strange problem in unity android build - texture and frame

Tags: unity, android, build-process

[image]

Suddenly the texture quality of Unity Android Build and the frame of the game was greatly degraded.

See the picture A and B. In image A the center lines on the road are sharper, but B is blurred. I want my game to look like A, not B.

What is surprising is that you can roll back the project to the point where it worked and then run the apk build again.

In the above picture, A is a screenshot of a normal time. I have installed apk backed up at that point.

B is a screenshot of when I built A after I rolled back the Unity project at the build time.

Both are the same project, but the build output is different. (Of course not good ...)

Of course I did not touch Unity, Java, Android SDK etc at the same time.

Of course, there is no configuration change on the testing phone as well.

It's just like this all of a sudden.

I even reinstalled the PC this morning.

I still have this problem.

Even if you build on a separate PC, you're having the same problem.

I build a project at another pc, mac book pro, but problem is still there.

Of cause, I factory-reset my test phone, but problem still there.

Test phone is Samsung Galaxy S4.

build environment is Windows 10, Unity 2017.

Comment: You should take a look at the android build settings window, and configure everything from there